# cURL request throwing "Improperly formatted request" error

Tags: api, curl

I am making a Curl request to this API but no matter what I do it is showing me an error

> MY API key = 34ca0e9b-ecdd-4736-a432-d87760ae0926

```
curl "https://www.lifeguard.insure/v1/quote" -H "Authorization: 34ca0e9b-ecdd-4736-a432-d87760ae0926" -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"category": "Auto","zipcode": "90293","age": 35, "gender": "Male", "key": "a2bf34ab-8509-4aa6-aa9e-13ae7917e1b8"}'
```

> {"errors": ["Improperly formatted request"]}

On the documentation it is showing me this `https://www.lifeguard.insure/docs/#http-request`

The code given is -

```
curl "https://www.lifeguard.insure/v1/quote" \
  -H "Authorization: 34ca0e9b-ecdd-4736-a432-d87760ae0926" \
  -X POST \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
        "category": "Auto",
        "zipcode": "90293",
        "age": 35,
        "gender": "Male",
        "key": "a2bf34ab-8509-4aa6-aa9e-13ae7917e1b8"
    }'
```

What is wrong at my site or it is a problem at thwe API's end?

Comment: You should probably regenerate/revoke your API key after posting it here.

Comment: NO problem ,I will generate a new Key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I use double quotes for the strings and escape the contained double quotes (`\"`) the request works:

```
curl "https://www.lifeguard.insure/v1/quote" -H "Authorization: 34ca0e9b-ecdd-4736-a432-d87760ae0926" -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"category\": \"Auto\",\"zipcode\": \"90293\",\"age\": 35, \"gender\": \"Male\", \"key\": \"a2bf34ab-8509-4aa6-aa9e-13ae7917e1b8\"}"
```

---

This seems to be a Windows specific issue, where you cannot use single-quotes in the terminal. The API doc probably generates cURL code for Linux envs.